# jQuery - parsing URL GET params to determine whether to show ajax spinner

Tags: javascript, url, jquery

This code is not currently working, but here's what I have:

```
App.Utils = {
  _spinnerDisabledAtQueryParam: function(request) {
    return /spinner\=false/.match(request.url);
  },
  showSpinner: function() {
    return $('#ajax-status').show();
  },
  hideSpinner: function() {
    return $('#ajax-status').hide();
  },
  bindSpinnerEvents: function(request) {
    $(document).on('ajaxStart', function() {
      if (!App.Utils._spinnerDisabledAtQueryParam(request)) {
        return App.Utils.showSpinner();
      }
    });
    return $(document).on('ajaxStop', function() {
      if ($.active === 0) {
        return App.Utils.hideSpinner();
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return App.Utils.bindSpinnerEvents(request);
});
```

As you can see, I am passing a mock request object to bindSpinnerEvents.  Let's assume I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/events?event_id=1&spinner=false
```

What I want to do is NOT show the spinner if the param spinner is set to true.  I've tried several different things but can't seem to get this to work.  I just started learning jQuery / Javascript.  Any help that you could provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (~window.location.search.search(/(?:^|[&;])spinnner=true(?:[&;]|$)/)) {
    // Hide spinner.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKm9F/).

The condition will be true if `spinner` is a GET param and its value is `true`.

The `~` operator turns the presence of a match to be *truthy*, so we don't need to compare against `-1`.

Comment: This code doesn't pick up the spinner param until at least two GET ajax requests are executed.

Answer (score 0):

u can try something like this

```
$(document).ready( function() {

            var name = 'spinner';
            var value;

              var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";  
              var regex = new RegExp( regexS );  
              var results = regex.exec('http://localhost:8080/events?event_id=1&spinner=false'); 
               if( results == null ){
                    value=  "";  
               }
              else {value = results[1]}   ;
              alert(value);
              if(value) {
                  $('#ajax-status').show();

              } else {
                  $('#ajax-status').hide();

              }
    };
```